# DirectoryIndex not working properly for rewritten URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, directoryindex

I have `domain.com` and `sub.domain.com` pointing to the same server and I'm using mod_rewrite to rewrite URLs for `sub.domain.com` to the `sub` subdirectory. I have the following `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

# Prevent infinite rewrite loop.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# Send all requests addressing sub.domain.com...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub.domain.com [NC]
# ...to the /sub directory.
RewriteRule ^ /sub%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

Within the `sub` directory I have `index.php` and no `index.html`, but requests to `http://sub.domain.com` seem to ignore `index.php` altogether and return 404. If I have `index.html` there, however, its is served. The only way I could get `index.php` to be served is to set

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

but that is not something I want to do for the entire site.

Oddly enough, URLs other than the document root exhibit normal `DirectoryIndex` behavior. For example, `http://sub.domain.com/search` tries looks for `sub/search/index.html` then `sub/search/index.php` before returning 404.

If I query the `sub` directory from the parent domain `http://domain.com/sub`, I'm able to see `index.php`, which leaves me completely dumbfounded with the issue.

I'd include the Apache error log, but I'm using shared hosting and have no way to increase logging verbosity. Also, I was unable to reproduce this error locally. The web hosting server is using Apache 2.4.3, and my local server is Apache 2.4.9.

Comment: try adding `DirectoryCheckHandler On` to your apache config? [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directorycheckhandler)

Comment: Oops, sorry for the delay. Looking at the docs for `DirectoryCheckHandler`, they state that "Releases prior to 2.4 implicitly act as if 'DirectoryCheckHandler ON' was specified." My local Apache server should have this directive OFF by default, and I guess the hosting server should have it OFF (since it's a 2.4 release). If `DirectoryCheckHandler` behavior is the rootcause, wouldn't I see it on both servers?

Comment: And either way, I wouldn't be able to set `DirectoryCheckHandler` on the hosted server since it's not available in that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, which includes Apache 2.4.7.

Here is my **workaround**. *Emulate* `mod_dir` with `mod_rewrite`, and disable `DirectoryIndex`.

```
#DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
DirectoryIndex disabled

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1index.html  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1index.php  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1index.htm  [L]
```

Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE**: Upgrading to Apache 2.4.10 fix the issue for me.

Thanks to [Ondřej Surý](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2) this can be done easily on Ubuntu 14.04 with apt:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2
```

p.s. OP confirmed this is fixed in Apache 2.4.9 too.

Comment: I actually ended up using a nearly identical workaround. Thanks for posting it!

Comment: Also I went with this workaround for another reason. I wanted directory URLs to not have trailing slashes (and explicitly removed them with mod_rewrite redirects). But because "`DirectoryIndex` will be evaluated only for directories requested with trailing slash" I used mod_rewrite again to emulate the indices. In retrospect it would have been much easier to keep the trailing slashes :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the [DirectoryCheckHandler](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directorycheckhandler) directive to `ON`.

The Apache docs say:

> Available in 2.4.8 and later. Releases prior to 2.4 implicitly act as if "DirectoryCheckHandler ON" was specified.

[mod_dir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html) used to always perform its checks no matter which handler was set and now it must be explicitly enabled when not using the default handler.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` statements were in use, which was preventing `DirectoryIndex` from being checked.  This fixed it.